# Debugging Help required to concatenate two char arrays in third one using function in C++

Tags: c++

I just can't figure out why it is not compiling.After spending an hour to it,i decided to get some help from you guys.According to my understandings the first "for" loop will surely copy whole string s1 to s3.I don't know why it crashes.Actually i am naive to programming more to be entitled as "Beginner to C++".
So i don't want to use built in function because i am learning concept of user defined functions.
I have called function in main() as string_cat(s1,s2);

```
 void string_cat(char *s1, char*s2){
    char s3[200]; int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s3[i] = s1[i];
    }
    while (s3[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    while (s2[j] != '\0')
    {
        s3[i++] = s2[j++];

    }
    s3[i] = NULL;

    cout << s3 << endl;

    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting the first `while` loop to do?  Also, you might want to get your terminology straight.  Compilation is the process of converting the .cpp file into an executable: .exe under Windows, or a.out / whatever under *nix / MacOS.  That part's going fine, the failure occurs when you actually run the program.

Comment: For what is `while (s3[i] != '\0') { i++; }` good? Be aware that `char s3[200];` leaves array `s3` uninitialized. So, you shouldn't read what is not (yet) written.

Comment: Have a look at [`strcat()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat). There is surely no internal buffer. The algorithm is probably: 1. search `'\0'` in `s1`. 2. copy `s2` to `s1` (beginning at address of `'\0'`) until `'\0'` in `s2` (including). 3. Return the original value of `s1` (If pointer is changed in loop it has to be copied before - but only the pointer, not the contents it is pointing to.) This sounds a bit dangerous concerning out of bound access but this is how it is defined. The caller of `strcat()` is responsible to provide sufficient memory in `s1`.

Comment: Don't stress the early learning days.  Making mistakes is OK.  "He that makes no mistakes makes nothing."   Learning from them is valuable and good experience.  You can't expect to pick up C++ overnight, it's a big complex language.  Work at it though, in time you'll become an expert.

Comment: In your for-loop you copy the characters, but not the terminating '\0', to s3. It seems more code should be added to make sure the terminating '\0' gets added to s3 immediately after the for-loop.

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve] please.  I added `int main() { string_cat("Hello ", "World"); }` and I got a couple of warnings (because a string literal cannot strictly be converted to `char *` and because `NULL` is a pointer, not a character usable as a null-terminator.), but it worked just fine.

Comment: If you change the signature of `string_cat` to `void string_cat(const char *s1, const char *s2)` that would get rid of one of the warnings, and made the penultimate line `s3[i] = '\0'` that would get rid of the other.

Comment: Code works just fine. Can you give use case when it crashes?

Comment: As a C++ beginner, I advise you to **not** think of  `char *` as strings. Use `std::string`, and think in terms of *operations on values*. Join strings with `std::string::append` (or if you are OK with non-commutativity, `+` and `+=`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your code working with minor changes:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


void string_cat(char *s1, char*s2)
{
    char s3[200]; int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        s3[i] = s1[i];
    }

    while (s2[j] != '\0')
    {
        s3[i++] = s2[j++];

    }
    s3[i] = '\0';

    cout << s3 << endl;

}

int main()
{
        char str1[5] = "abcd";
        char str2[5] = "efgh";

        string_cat(str1, str2);
}
```

You should write:  `s3[i] = '\0';`

Compile:

```
$ g++ StringMerge.cpp -o StringMerge.o
```

Run:

```
$ ./StringMerge.o
abcdefgh
```